# How to show IF-THEN rules in weka using java code

Tags: java, weka

How to show IF-THEN rules in weka using java code

I have code for displaying rules in graph form but how can i get IF-THEN rules.

I want to output like this

```
outlook = sunny
|   humidity = high: no (3.0)
|   humidity = normal: yes (2.0)
outlook = overcast: yes (4.0)
outlook = rainy
|   windy = TRUE: no (2.0)
|   windy = FALSE: yes (3.0)
```

this is my java code for Displaying Graph forms rules

```
 public class Evaluteagain extends HttpServlet
 {
 /**
  * 
  */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter p = resp.getWriter();       
    p.write("\n");

    DataSource source = null;



    try {

        source = new DataSource("E:/data/test/finalcsv.csv");



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Instances dataset = null;


    try {
        dataset = source.getDataSet();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //set class index to the last attribute
    dataset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes()-1);



    //create and build the classifier!

    J48 tree = new J48();


    try {
        tree.buildClassifier(dataset);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




      // display classifier


        final javax.swing.JFrame jf = 
           new javax.swing.JFrame("Tree Visualizer: J48");
         jf.setSize(500,400);
         jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         TreeVisualizer tv = null;
        try {
            tv = new TreeVisualizer(null,
                 tree.graph(),
                 new PlaceNode2());
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
         jf.getContentPane().add(tv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         jf.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
             jf.dispose();
           }
         });

         jf.setVisible(true);
         tv.fitToScreen();
        }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This below code is for how to show IF-THEN rules in weka using java code
in this code i generate rules in Servlet and print in console ...

```
 public class Ifthenrules extends HttpServlet
{
/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {


    DataSource source = null;

    try {

        //input dataset
        source = new DataSource("E:/data/test/finalcsv.csv");

        } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Instances dataset = null;

        try {
        dataset = source.getDataSet();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //set class index to the last attribute
        dataset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes()-1);

        //create and build the classifier!

        J48 tree = new J48();

        try {

        tree.buildClassifier(dataset);

        } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String testt = "Ifthenrules";

        try {

        // Generate rules in IF-THEN form

        tree.toSource(testt);

        } catch (Exception e3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        //now print rules
        System.out.println(tree.toString());                

        }
   }
```